# How to import a csv with blank cells

Tags: r, dataframe

When I import a csv, it appears as a dataframe with this format

```
firstcol <- c("A","","D","Z")
seccol <- c("W","Y","C","")
thircol <- c("","H","Q","M")

df <- data.frame(firstcol,seccol,thircol)

#    > df
#      firstcol seccol thircol
#    1        A      W        
#    2               Y       H
#    3        D      C       Q
#    4        Z              M
```

When I type `levels(df$firstcol)`

The output is:
   [`1] ""  "A" "D" "Z"`

How can I import my csv such that the cells are being read as empty cells and not as an observation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `na.strings = ""` so that the blank cells will be read as `NA`

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = '', 
       strip.white = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the values as NA while reading the .csv

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', header=T, na.strings=c(""))
```